# .NET Native компиляция

Tags: c#, .net, native

Как скомпилировать проект в .NET Native? Нужного пункта нету, как его включить?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В текущем Visual Studio компиляция в .NET Native поддерживается только для проектов UWP с целевой платформой Windows 10.

Для удобства отладки, .NET Native применяется лишь для Release-режима компиляции.

Если вы создадите такой проект, и зайдёте в его свойства, вы увидите:

[image: ну кое-где можно, да]

Источник информации: [Getting Started with .NET Native | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/net-native/getting-started-with-net-native).

Comment: Спасибо огромное, очень помог

Comment: @Hol0ZeN: Пожалуйста!

Comment: панос ___________

Comment: @МаксБурцев: А в чём вопрос-то?